# Bootstrap Grid Columns Not Aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a responsive grid in bootstrap with four products across the page (with four columns).  I want the boxes for each product to line up perfectly across the page.  I'm having an issue when there are a different amount of lines of text for the title.  Can see the issue below (note I haven't added the fourth product as of yet).

https://ibb.co/kE1UH5

Here is my code for HTML

```
 <div class="container bg">
 <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
      <div class="row">
        {% for deal in deals %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 rwrapper">
          <div class="rlisting">
        <div class="col-md-12 nopad hover11">
            <figure><img src="{{ deal.image.url }}" class="img-responsive" style="width:250px;height:250px;margin:20px"></figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 nopad">
          <h5>{{ deal.retailer}}</h5>
           <h3>{{ deal.title}}</h3>
            <h3><strong>{{deal.price}}</strong><h3>
           <div class="rfooter">
             <i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i><a href="{{deal.link}}" role="button" class="btn btn-success">See Deal</a>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

 </div>
</div>
```

and CSS here:

```
.bg{background-color: #dfdfdf;}
.rwrapper{padding: 1px;}
.rlisting{background-color: #fff;overflow: hidden;}
.rlisting img{width: 100%}
.nopad{padding:0;}
.rfooter{width: 50%;}
.rlisting h5,.rlisting p{padding:0 15px; font-style:italic;}
.rlisting h3,.rlisting p{padding:0 15px;}

/* Opacity #1 */
.hover11 figure img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover11 figure:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
}

.column {
    margin: 15px 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.column:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.column::after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.column div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    padding: 0;
}
.column div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.column div span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
figure {
    margin: 0;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
figure:hover+span {
    bottom: -36px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom:-1px;
    border-radius:0;
}
#submenu {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    min-height:0;
}
.navbar-nav{margin:0}
.collapsing {
    display:none;
}
.jumbotron {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

 .nav-2{
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  background:#fff;
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
}

.container-2{margin-top:120px}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `scss` rather than `css` to make this easier, and set the height of the title to be a multiple of the maximum number of lines you would like to display.

```
$line-height: 20px;
$line-count: 3;    //Example of 3 lines
.title {
    line-height: $line-height;
    height: $line-count * $line-height;
}
```

You should then also limit the length of text that you are displaying to a sensible limit that will not be longer than 3 lines (and add an ellipsis if desired).

This could also of course just be done with `css` and setting it to 60px in this example.

Comment: thanks that seemed to do the trick--used a height of 60px and a line-height of 20px in CSS.  only issue is that there is not much spacing between my lines.  i tried increasing height but not helping.  any ideas?